# Passing variable to view from controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can something like this be done? I want to pass a variable from a public function to my view.

```
public function index() {

    $home_data['username']  = "myname";
            $home_data['cool'] = $this->variable;

    $this->load->view('home_view', $home_data);
}

public function a_function() {

      public $variable = "cool";      

}
```

**//EDIT//**

This is what I m actually trying to accomplish and I m stuck.

`get_two` gets two items from a table. I want to add the two items to two variables and pass them to the view.

```
public function get_two() {

           $get_results = $this->home_model->get_two_brands();

            if($get_results != false){

              $html = '';

               foreach($get_results as $result){
                     $html .= '<li><a href="#" class="pick" id="'.$result->id.'">'.$result->brand.'</a></li>';
                }

                 $result = array('status' => 'ok', 'content' => $html);
                    header('Content-type: application/json');
                    echo json_encode($result);
                    exit();

            }

}//public function get_two() {
```

Should I create two functions like this? But I don't know how to pass the `$get_results` array from `get_two` to the below functions. I tried `public $get_results = $this->model ... etc` but that didn't work.

```
public function result_one() {
    return $resultOne = $get_results[0];
}

public function result_two() {
    return $resultTwo = $get_results[1];
}
```

Comment: And how the view looks like ?

Comment: The view ... what does that matter? Let's say I try to do something like this: `echo $cool;` I want it to be "cool".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I've got the question correctly but what you're trying to achieve is something like this?

```
public function index() {

    $home_data['username']  = "myname";
    $home_data['cool'] = $this->a_function();

    $this->load->view('home_view', $home_data);
}

public function a_function() {

  return $variable = "cool";
```

}

/**** AFTER EDIT ****/

Things get complicated (possibly because of my english comprehension).

you said

> get_two gets two items from a table. I want to add the two items to two variables and pass them to the view.

So from the function `get_two()` you need to get and use the result in this way?

```
public function index() {

    $home_data['username']  = "myname";
    $home_data['cool'] = $this->get_two(); // <- here?

    $this->load->view('home_view', $home_data);
}
```

So you can try with:

```
public function get_two() {

    $get_results = $this->home_model->get_two_brands();

    if($get_results != false){

       return $get_results;
    }
}
```

and then

```
public function index() {

    $home_data['username']  = "myname";

    $home_data['cool'] = $this->get_two();

    $this->load->view('home_view', $home_data);
}
```

and inside you home_view :

```
<?php

foreach($home_data['cool'] as $result){
    echo '<li><a href="#" class="pick" id="'.$result->id.'">'.$result->brand.'</a></li>';
}

?>
```

/**** AFTER NEW QUESTION ****/

> I need the ids of the two choices as two distinct variables

So change the `index function` this way:

```
public function index() {

    $home_data['username']  = "myname";
    $home_data['cool'] = $this->get_two(); // <- maybe you don't need this anymore

    list($result1, $result2) = $this->get_two();

    $home_data['resultId1'] = $result1->id;
    $home_data['resultId2'] = $result2->id;

    $this->load->view('home_view', $home_data);
}
```

Now you're able to use `$home_data['resultId1']` and `$home_data['resultId1']` inside your view.

Comment: @ilpaijin, your code is correct.  Ciprian should describe what error is getting.

Comment: it does get complicated. but you re on the right track. except that my  view doesn t load ... it just loads the results from get_two. i am also loading it dynamicAlly with jquwery

Comment: Yeah ... but I add the list items with jQuery. That's not what I want. I two options, out of which users pick one of them. And as you can see, I have the id of the options set as the id of the a href `id="'.$result->id.'"`. I need the ids of the two choices as two distinct variables that way I can send them back to the controller when adding to the userPick table to make sure that the user doesn't change the id of the href.

Comment: So just edit the index function? I m getting internal server error.

Comment: tried doing this: `list($result1, $result2) = $this->get_two();` but my view displays `{"status":"ok","content":"<li><a href=\"#\" class=\"pick\" id=\"22\">option1<\/a><\/li><li><a href=\"#\" class=\"pick\" id=\"1\">option2<\/a><\/li>"}` only thing on whole page. right at the top. If I do this `list($result1, $result2) = get_two();` I get internal server error.

Comment: Now, you're retrieving this content from an ajax call. Now by parsing  the json content from `"content":` you're able to insert it into your html.

Comment: Yeah, but how do I get the two ids as php variables? I don't know how to do that.

Comment: If you are using `foreach($get_results as $result){ $html .= '<li><a href="#" class="pick" id="'.$result->id.'">'.$result->brand.'</a></li>';}` you should have the id with the correct value

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the codeigniter framework so this is why I asked for a part of your view but it looks pretty simple as I check in the doc. And the doc's are not bad there.

Check for [Adding Dynamic Data to the View](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)

`public_function()` should return something, for ex:

```
function public_function() {
 return 'groovy';
}
```

Then call it in the controller:

```
public function index() {

    $home_data['username']  = "myname";
    $home_data['cool'] = $this->public_function();

    $this->load->view('home_view', $home_data);
}
```

Then add to the view somewhere
`<?php echo $home_data['cool'];?>`

I assume it's wrapped in some class. So if you cannot `return` the value you need (for ex. function already returns something else) then do something like this:

```
class Someclass {

 public $some_class_variable;

 function public_function() {
  $this->some_class_variable = 'groovy';
 }

 function index() {
  $home_data['cool'] = $this->some_class_variable;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also define the variable in the constructor, this is one way .

CODE:

```
public function __construct(){
$this->variable = "cool"; 
}
public function index() {

    $home_data['username']  = "myname";
            $home_data['cool'] = $this->variable;

    $this->load->view('home_view', $home_data);
}
```